# How to map Ctrl + Delete to Fn + Opt + Delete with Karabiner-Elements

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner

I would like to map Ctrl + Delete on a Windows keyboard to Fn + Opt + Delete on a Macbook keyboard, so it deletes the next word after the cursor.

I can't figure out how to represent Fn + Opt + Delete in the json, how would I modify the following?

```
{
    "conditions": [{"type": "frontmost_application_unless", "bundle_identifiers": ["^com\\.sublimetext\\.3$"]}],
    "from": {"key_code": "delete_forward", "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["left_control"]}},
    "to": /* What should I put here? */,
    "type": "basic"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually quite obvious, I have no idea why I didn't try to obvious solution. Took me a couple days to figure it out. All I needed to do was add the Opt/Alt modifier.

```
{
    "conditions": [{"type": "frontmost_application_unless", "bundle_identifiers": [
        "^com\\.sublimetext\\.3$",
        "^com\\.google\\.Chrome$",
        "^com\\.jetbrains\\.pycharm$"
    ]}],
    "from": {"key_code": "delete_forward", "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["left_control"]}},
    "to": [{"key_code": "delete_forward", "modifiers": ["left_alt"]}],
    "type": "basic"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Fn</kbd>  is usually evaluated within the keyboard, before transmission. It doesn't generate its own event.

According to Key Codes,  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>  generates this data...

```
Key Down
    Characters: 
    Unicode:        63272 / 0xf728
    Keys:       ⌥⌦
    Key Code:   117 / 0x75
    Modifiers:  8913216 / 0x880140 ⓘ
```

Maybe you could use that to initiate the replacement - I don't use Karabiner so can't test.

*`Characters: ` doesn't actually generate any printable character on my machine.

Comment: Hm I think 0x75 is just `delete_forward` in Karabiner, which is Fn + Delete, but need a way to represent Fn + Opt + Delete somehow.

Comment: It clearly shows opt/forward delete... which is what you actually generate if you hit Fn/opt/back delete. You need to include the modifier code to get the entire command.Get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can import one of the predefined rules that are maintained by the community, or look at the JSON definition of those to see how it's done.

For example the "*Map Ctrl+Backspace-Delete to Fn+Backward-Delete (suppr current character)*" rule.

See https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=Map%20Ctrl%2BBackspace-Delete